# Five minute answer edit window failed?

Tags: support, revisions-list, timestamps

(Pardon me if this is a duplicate.  I did try to find one but I am apparently not good at navigating Meta.)

On [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) I experienced something I don't think I've seen before.  I posted an answered and edit it three minutes later.  Instead of the edit being combined with the original as it usually is it appears as a separate edit.  The post in question is:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/86693/revisions

The timestamp of the original is 02:23:23Z and the timestamp of the edit is 02:26:37Z.

Did I do something unusual to produce this result?

Comment: Happened to me once, couldn't replicate, so I ignored it. Did someone comment on it before you edited? (might be unrelated, but that's the only notable thing I remember from my incident.)

Comment: @muru It seems it was the comment that did it.  I guess I hadn't run into the May 2015 changes yet.  (See linked duplicate.)